# JSON array is unable to transmit a String having backslash

Tags: json, backslash

i am tranmitting a message via JSONArray but getting reponse code 500. 
reason is that My Message String contains a character '\'.

String s="apples $54\KG"

Comment: Are you coding in Java, JavaScript, something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

back slash charahter is not supproted by GSM.

Answer (score 0):

Backslash is an escape character. Use `\\` instead. There is a `JSON.stringify` function too that might help.